# Tkinter window focus on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm writing an application in Python with the Tkinter GUI framework. It listens for keyboard and mouse events, so it must have focus. When it is launched from a terminal in Ubuntu, the following code works:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.focus_force()

def key(event):
    print "pressed", event.char

def callback(event):
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y 

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_force()

root.mainloop()
```

However, when launched from a terminal in Mac OS X 10.8.4 (stock Python 2.7.2), focus is retained by the terminal emulator until the user clicks on the window. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried this and it worked well for me:

```
from os import system
from platform import system as platform

# set up your Tk Frame and whatnot here...

if platform() == 'Darwin':  # How Mac OS X is identified by Python
    system('''/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to set frontmost of process "Python" to true' ''')
```

Of course, that'll bring your entire application to the front, not just a specific window, but after you do that, you can then use `focus_force()` on a specific frame or window and that'll get moved to become the frontmost of all your application windows.

For those interested, I didn't write the `system()` call myself. I found it in [this thread on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/tcl/mailman/message/23718545/).

The fact that I put the `system()` call within an if block that verifies this is running on OS X makes the solution cross platform - my understanding is that `focus_force()` works on all other platforms exactly as you want, and just performing it after the `system()` invocation wouldn't cause any problems in OS X, either.

Answer (score 2):

came here wondering the same question, but I found this wise sounding answer from Kevin Walzer which suggests to use `py2app`:

> Yes, this is standard  behavior for OS X. Running an app in Terminal 
>   keeps focus in the Terminal unless you switch by clicking windows. The 
>   Command-Tab behavior is determined by the windowing system, not by a 
>   newly spawned process.
>
> The way around this is to wrap your application up in a standard Mac app 
>   bundle using py2app. The average Mac user isn't going to launch a 
>   Python-based game from the command line.
>
> Kevin

(from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/ZPO8ZN5dx3M)

Comment: You can also use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). I like it since I can make both Mac App bundles and Windows executables.

Answer (score -1):

Do wait_visibility and event_generate help ?

eg. something like -

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    print "pressed", event.char

def callback(event):
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y 

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

frame.focus_set()

root.wait_visibility()
root.event_generate('<Button-1>', x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```